# calculate kolmogorov complexity in the game of life

Tags: complexity-theory, cellular-automata

In order to calculate the Kolmogorov complexity one has to "count" the minimum amount of operations it takes for a certain task(from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836134/how-to-compute-kolmogorov-complexity-of-an-algorithm)). Since the game of life (or cellular automata) outputs are non predictable and not compressible the amounts of rules applied should equal the Kolmogorov complexity? Or does the fact that a certain combination of cells is achievable via different paths make it "compressible" because there is a most efficient path to the combination(but that shouldn't matter if I'm only interested in the Kolmogorov complexity of a certain combination of cells after n iterations)?

thx

Comment: "the game of life (or cellular automata) outputs are non predictable and not compressible" This is false. The outputs of Game of Life contain no [orphan patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_of_Eden_(cellular_automaton)#Existence_of_orphans) so they are definitely compressible.

Comment: Admittedly I’m not good in explaining things but I also mentioned that “garden of Eden phenomena” here “ Or does the fact that a certain combination of cells is achievable via different paths make it "compressible" because there is a most efficient path to the combination”. But after that I also mentioned that for my question that maybe does not matter because I don’t care about the complexity of the final pattern but for the complexity leading to the pattern

Comment: See also (possible duplicate): https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/145203/simple-measurement-of-complexity-in-game-of-life